# Batch file to sort txt after appending from other txt

Tags: windows, file, sorting, batch-file

I'm wanting a batch file that I can drag a text file onto (preferrably multiple text files at once) which will read each text file line by line and add each line to a specified destination text file. Destination text file will not contain any duplicated lines, and will be sorted alphabetically. A source file will never contain the same line twice, but may contain non-alphanumeric characters such as: { - : _ ~ !

Example:

a.txt:

```
apple
banana
garbage carrot
{Elmer Fudd}
```

b.txt

```
1 tequila
2 tequila
3 tequila
garbage carrot
{Bugs Bunny}
```

destination.txt before:

```
{daffy duck}
floor
```

destination.txt after dragging a.txt and b.txt onto the batch file:

```
{Bugs Bunny}
{daffy duck}
{Elmer Fudd}
1 tequila
2 tequila
3 tequila
apple
banana
floor
garbage carrot
```

I've got it started:

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set "sourcefile=%~1"
echo "%sourcefile%" > temp.txt
for /f "delims=;" %%F in (%sourcefile%) do (
    echo %%F>>temp.txt
)

del /q destination.txt
ren temp.txt destination.txt
```

It copies the file dragged into a temp file, but I can't figure out how to get it sorted. The sort command does NOT work for me, it just hangs the program up. All help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: doing it alphabetically with special characters in batch will be **very** hard.

Comment: I'm aware of the difficulty. I'm currently stuck, I can't even get it to copy non-special characters into the temp file. It keeps opening the originally dragged file instead of reading it:

`REM @echo off`  
`REM setlocal disabledelayedexpansion`  
`echo "%~1" > temp.txt`  
`pause`  
`for /f "delims=;" %%F in ('%~1') do (`  
`echo %%F>>temp.txt`  
`)`  
`pause`  
`del /q destination.txt`  
`ren temp.txt destination.txt`  
`pause`

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "prev="
echo "%~1"
copy /y destination.txt+"%~1" temp.txt >nul

(    
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('sort temp.txt') do (
  if "!prev!" neq "%%F" echo(%%F
  set "prev=%%F"
)
)>destination.txt
del temp.txt
```

should work for you (I've not tried it)

No need to process the new file with `for /f` - `copy a+b c` concatenates a and b into c. The `/y` forces overwrite of the destination if it already exists.

Then process each line, echoing the line read from the `sort` if this line does not match the previous - but "enclosing the strings in quotes" so that batch knows to process the string as a single unit if it contains spaces or other separators.

The `(...echo ...)>file` format (re)creates file with the `echo`ed data rather than sending the data to the screen.

Comment: the sort command causes the batch to hang, unfortunately. Not sure why, it's not like it's sorting through billions of lines. My testing files have only 3 lines of single letters each. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Save as batch file. This is an hybrid batch/jscript file. The file processing/sorting is done in the batch part. Then, the javascript part is invoked to eliminate the duplicated lines.

EDITED - To adapt to comments

```
@if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off
rem **** batch zone *********************************************************

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

rem If there are no files, nothing to do
    if "%~1"=="" goto endProcess

rem Configure the output final file 
    set "outputFile=destination.txt"
    if not exist "%outputFile%" >"%outputFile%" break

rem Configure and initialize temporary file
    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%.tmp"
    find /v "" <"%outputFile%" >"%tempFile%"

rem Iterate over the file list sending output to temporary file and deleting input file
    for %%a in (%*) do (
        find /v "" <"%%a" >>"%tempFile%"
        rem del /q "%%a" 2>nul 
    )

rem Process temporary file into outpufile, sorting and eliminating duplicates    
    type "%tempFile%" | sort  | cscript //nologo //e:Javascript "%~f0" > "%outputFile%"

rem Cleanup    
    del /q "%tempFile%" 2>nul

:endProcess 
    endlocal
    exit /b

@end
// **** Javascript zone *****************************************************
    var stdin=WScript.StdIn, stdout=WScript.StdOut, previous=null, current;
    while (!stdin.AtEndOfStream){
        if (previous !== (current=stdin.ReadLine())) stdout.WriteLine(current);
        previous = current;
    };
```

Comment: Thank you, MC ND. I see how this works for the most part. It seems to work flawlessly with two files, but dragging more than two files at a time causes it to overlap some of the lines. Also, if I want it to delete the source files as it goes along, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: @RADRaze2KX, the line overlapping happens if the lines in the input files do not end with a CRLF. Changed the `type` command with a `find` filter to force the inclusion of line terminators. Added a loop over the input files to allow deletion as they are processed (but included a `rem`, remove it if it works for you).

Comment: this one seems to work perfectly on my desktop (Windows Server 2012) but doesn't seem to work on my laptop running Windows 8.1. I have not tried other operating systems yet, but do you know why this might be? This is a perfect program so far, thank you for your diligence.

Comment: I removed the REM and it doesn't delete the file. That's OK, i think I prefer it that way right now. Is there a way I can take the finished file and put it somewhere once the javascript is done manipulating it? I have a code to upload the file to my web server but am not sure where to stick it. I could always make a parent batch file and run it to run this batch file followed by the uploader.

Comment: @RADRaze2KX, call your uploader after the cleanup and before the `:endProcess`. At this time you have the file and can call the rest of the process. For the OS question, it depends on your configuration. It should work from XP up. What does not work in your 8.1?

Comment: It wouldn't copy anything at all in Windows 8.1. I'm not sure why, not really too big of a concern right now so long as it works on my server. This is going to save me SO much time. I'm using this program to add lines from a log file generated by PCDecrapifier to the master list it uses to remove malware from. Originally, I was adding these entries line by line, alphabetically, by hand, and one log file could take me up to half an hour to work through. This will make it instant! Thank you so much!

Comment: Terribly sorry, it works. I've been a space case and I don't use Stackoverflow often. I have awarded your points but I apparently need 15 reputation for it to reflect. I've been using your script for two years with no issues, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right then this should suffice:

```
@echo off
:loop
   type "%~1" >>"c:\destination.txt"
   shift 
   if not "%~1"=="" goto :loop
sort < "c:\destination.txt" > "%temp%\random file.txt"
move "%temp%\random file.txt" "c:\destination.txt"
```